# Get v-model value in child component Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, prop

I am using a Vue2Editor in my Vuetify App. I have made a component of `text-editor` as:

```
<vue-editor
  :value="text"
  @input="updateText"
></vue-editor>
```

And it's props are:

```
props: {
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
},
```

For the validation, I am calling it in the parent component and giving it v-model *(VeeValidate requires it)*:

```
<text-editor
  :text="UnitData.Details"
  v-model="UnitData.Details"
  @updateText="UnitData.Details = $event"
  data-vv-name="details"
  v-validate="'required|min:100'"
/>
```

Now look, `text` and `v-model` have same values, I need to get v-model in my child component *(used `vModel` prop but not worked)*, so that I don't end up with duplicate code, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-editor` component:

```html
<vue-editor
  :value="value"
  @input="updateText"
></vue-editor>
```

```js
props: {
  value: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
},
methods: {
  updateText () {
    this.$emit('input', this.value)
  }
}
```

parent

```html
<text-editor
  v-model="UnitData.Details"
/>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: I cannot find the answer here. `this.value` doesn't work for me, nor `this.modelValue` or `this.$parent.data` (which is undefined). I use Vue 3.